# interpreting multcompTs from multcompView in R

Tags: r, tukey-hsd-test

This graph was created using multcompBoxplot (from multcompView), and I'm having a difficult time interpreting what the mulcompTs of this graph are telling me in terms of differences between my response variable in different years (y axis). I'd be grateful to anybody who's fluent in stats-ese who'd be willing to describe it to me!

[image: Image generated by mulcompBoxplot function in multcompView to include connecting letters report and multcompT]